# TreeViewItem Virtualization and custom DependencyProperty (C# and WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, virtualization, dependency-properties

## Intro

I have a problem with the WPF TreeView control an Virtualization. I guess I reached the possibilities with this control and kinda found out why. Maybe someone can help find the best solution for this.

## Problem

I have a custom TreeListView control inherited from TreeView and TreeListViewItem inherited from TreeViewItem. For The TreeListView im using Virtualization. I added a DependencyProperty to TreeListViewItem.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsItemSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "IsItemSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(TreeListViewItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsItemSelectedChanged)
    )
  ;

public bool IsItemSelected
{
  get { return (bool)GetValue(IsItemSelectedProperty); }
  set { SetValue(IsItemSelectedProperty, value); }
}
```

With Virtualization active the DP is either (VirtualizationMode = Recycling) wrongly used for new items when scrolling or (VirtualizationMode = Normal) not there anymore.

## Cause

TreeView is not saving Properties in Virtualization mode. I digged through the code of TreeViewItem and found the code thats "causing" this.

TreeViewItem.cs line 910 ClearItemContainer function:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TreeViewItem.cs

```cs
// Right now we have a hard-coded list of DPs we want to save off.  In the future we could provide a 'register' API
// so that each ItemsControl could decide what DPs to save on its containers. Maybe we define a virtual method to
// retrieve a list of DPs the type is interested in.  Alternatively we could have the contract
// be that ItemsControls use the ItemStorageService inside their ClearContainerForItemOverride by calling into StoreItemValues.
```

In Helper.cs line 1554:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Helper.cs,de11b95141f7f543

```cs
// Since ItemValueStorage is private and only used for TreeView and Grouping virtualization we hardcode the DPs that we'll store in it.
// If we make this available as a service to the rest of the platform we'd come up with some sort of DP registration mechanism.
private static readonly int[] ItemValueStorageIndices = new int[] {
    ItemValueStorageField.GlobalIndex,
    TreeViewItem.IsExpandedProperty.GlobalIndex,
    Expander.IsExpandedProperty.GlobalIndex,
    GroupItem.DesiredPixelItemsSizeCorrectionFactorField.GlobalIndex,
    VirtualizingStackPanel.ItemsHostInsetProperty.GlobalIndex};
```

So the only Property saved is the IsExpandedProperty. And it's not possible to add own Properties.

## What to do?

Is there some other way I'm not seeing to add Properties?
Is there a way to save the Properties on my own?